# How can I draw an image from the HTML5 File API on Canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawimage, fileapi

I would like to draw an image opened with the HTML5 File API on a canvas.

In the `handleFiles(e)` method, I can access the File with `e.target.files[0]` but I can't draw that image directly using `drawImage`. How do I draw an image from the File API on HTML5 canvas?

Here is the code I have used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    input.addEventListener('change', handleFiles);
}

function handleFiles(e) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(e.target.files[0], 20,20);
    alert('the image is drawn');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>
<input type="file" id="input"/>
<canvas width="400" height="300" id="canvas"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You have a `File` instance which is not an image.

To get an image, use `new Image()`. The `src` needs to be an URL referencing to the selected `File`. You can use `URL.createObjectURL` to get an URL referencing to a `Blob` (a `File` is also a `Blob`): http://jsfiddle.net/t7mv6/86/.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 20,20);
    alert('the image is drawn');
}
img.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
```

**Note:** be sure to revoke the object url when you are done with it otherwise you'll leak memory.  If you're not doing anything too crazy, you can just stick a `URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src)` in the `img.onload` function.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File
- http://html5demos.com/file-api

Comment: Please attach `onload` before `src`. The `load` event can trigger between those two lines. (If the image is cached, etc)

Comment: @Raynos: Thanks. (Though the file must have been loaded extremely super fast in that case...)

Comment: Out of curiosity could you reference where it says "setting `.src` to a Blob/File" should work in the HTML5 spec? I have a slight snag that this might be a proprietary extension. It happens to work in Chrome / FF6 (Don't have opera, IE10 or Saf nightlies around to test)

Comment: @Raynos: I'm not setting the `src` of a `File`. Rather there are ready-to-go `File`s inside `e.target.files` available.

Comment: `img.src = event.target.result;` your setting the `.src` of an Image to the `File/Blob` in `result`

Comment: Thanks, this also works, but only online in Chrome, not if I have the .html file locally.

Comment: @Raynos: My fault, I misread. It looks like this answers your doubt: http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-readAsDataURL. `Set the result attribute to be blob's data content represented as a Data URL [DataURL]; on getting, the result attribute returns the (complete) data of blob as a Data URL`. Obviously the Data URL can be set to the src of an `Image`; this will load fine.

Comment: @Jonas: Won't be fixed: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=60889.

Comment: @pimvdb thanks for clearing that up. I was looking for that :)

Comment: @Raynos, it is my understanding that the `onload` event cannot be fired until *after* the currently executing script has finished, at which point the `onload` event will have been bound, which means that there is no issue with the order in which the `src` and `onload` attributes are set.

Comment: @zzzzBov implementation specific. Some browsers are known to fire `onload` immediately when you set `.src` because it synchronously checks the cache and loads immediately. You need really thorough stress testing to see what is "safe" or always set `onload` before `src`

Comment: @Raynos, if you've got an example that can show this effect i'd be interested to see it.

Comment: @zzzzBov this is known to happen for `Image` in IE when the src is an URL. I don't know how IE10 handles blob urls but I'd rather just set `onload` before `src` then worry about this. [Test](http://jsfiddle.net/puksP/1/) however I don't have a copy of IE lying around.

Comment: @Raynos, very interesting indeed. I could get the issue to crop up in IE9 compatibility mode, but I can't easily check IE7&8 to see where the issue lies (IE9 compat mode is similar to IE7, but not identical). Either way, I've learned something new.

Answer (score 16):

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/YVMfr/16/)

```
function handleFiles(e) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 20, 20);    
    }
    img.src = url;   
}
```

[`window.URL.createObjectUrl`<sup>*docs*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.URL.createObjectURL)

You could also use the `FileReader` instead to create the object URL.

The [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader) has slightly better browser support.

The `FileReader` approach works in FF6 / Chrome. I'm not certain whether setting `Img.src` to a `Blob` is valid and cross-browser though.

Creating object urls is the correct way to do it.

**Edit:**

As mentioned in the commment `window.URL` support whilst offline seems unavailable in FF6/Chrome.

Comment: This works, but only online. If I try this with a local .html file in Chrome it doesn't work.

Comment: The FileReader approach didn't work locally neither... Thanks.

Comment: @Jonas that may be a permissions thing. I wouldn't be suprised if they are blocked by default. Turning it on is probably finding some obscure flag.

Comment: @Jonas Seems like the obscure flag is `--allow-file-access-from-files.` for chrome. [Reference](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=60889#hc4)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a [complete example (Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/kepd5d40/3/) using `FileReader` (which has better browser support as mentioned by Raynos). In this example I also scale Canvas to fit the image.

In real life example you might scale the image to some maximum so that your form will not blow up ;-). Here is an [example with scaling (Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/kepd5d40/5/).

```js
var URL = window.webkitURL || window.URL;

window.onload = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    input.addEventListener('change', handleFiles, false);
    
    // set original canvas dimensions as max
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas.dataMaxWidth = canvas.width;
    canvas.dataMaxHeight = canvas.height;
}

function handleFiles(e) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    var reader  = new FileReader();
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    // load to image to get it's width/height
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        // setup scaled dimensions
        var scaled = getScaledDim(img, ctx.canvas.dataMaxWidth, ctx.canvas.dataMaxHeight);
        // scale canvas to image
        ctx.canvas.width = scaled.width;
        ctx.canvas.height = scaled.height;
        // draw image
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0
            , ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height
        );
    }
    // this is to setup loading the image
    reader.onloadend = function () {
        img.src = reader.result;
    }
    // this is to read the file
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

// returns scaled dimensions object
function getScaledDim(img, maxWidth, maxHeight) {
    var scaled = {
        ratio: img.width / img.height,
        width: img.width,
        height: img.height
    }
    if (scaled.width > maxWidth) {
        scaled.width = maxWidth;
        scaled.height = scaled.width / scaled.ratio;
    }
    if (scaled.height > maxHeight) {
        scaled.height = maxHeight;
        scaled.width = scaled.height / scaled.ratio;
    }
    return scaled;
}
```

```css
canvas {
    border:1px solid black
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="input"/>
<div>
    <canvas width="400" height="300" id="canvas"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Answers should show code in the question, not only in an external link.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't think that option was available on stackO back in 2015 , but I added the code.

Comment: I was on Stack Overflow back in 2015. You could add code to your answer back then too. Maybe not in a Snippet, but you could definitely add code :P.