# How to execute a function when jQuery is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a bookmarklet and using jQuery for it (with noConflict). I need to wait for jQuery to load, to execute all the jQuery code.

I know I can check with `typeof $` for jQuery, but I'm actually more looking for an event handler. Right now I'm just using `setTimeout` with a delay of 1s, because jQuery is proberly loaded then. 
I feel this is not a good solution. It's not clean code and relies on jQuery to load in 1s.

Is there any other way to afford this?

Comment: Are you dynamically appending jQuery to the DOM in the bookmarklet?

Comment: Yep. I'm doing that via appendChild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say you're appending it dynamically, you could make use of `onload`:

```
var elem = document.createElement('script');
elem.onload = function() {
    // script is loaded, you can now do things with jQuery
};
elem.src = 'path to jquery';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(elem);
```

Comment: Ah, this looks good and seems to work! :) Thanks. I wasn't aware of that event handler.

Comment: @dotweb: Cheers. Just to make it sure, it's advisable to put `onload` before setting `src`. Otherwise, the script might have loaded before you set the `onload` event (if it's a small script or loaded very fast), and the handler will not execute anymore.

Comment: Thanks! I actually put the `onload` after the `src`. Now it's the other way around! :)

Comment: @pimvdb, setting the `src` attribute does **not** start the script loading. the `script` element will only begin being loaded when it is added to the document *and* the currently running script has finished. The `appendChild` line adds the `script` element to the document, so when the script has finished executing, the `script` element will load. There is no issue on which order which attribute is added.

Comment: @zzzzBov: I messed it up with `Image`. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @pimvdb if you're talking about the `img` element, there's no issue with the attribute order there either for exactly the same reasons.

Comment: @zzzzBov: I was once told otherwise in fact: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775767/how-can-i-draw-an-image-from-the-html5-file-api-on-canvas/6776055#6776055.

Comment: @pimvdb, Raynos is incorrect in this case. Even if the image was fully loaded somehow after you set the `src` attribute, it would have to wait until the currently executing code was finished before the event could be fired, at which point the handler would already be attached. If you think there's a chance I'm incorrect, I urge you to produce an example where an item is loaded without error *and* where the event doesn't fire.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Since I cannot reproduce what Raynos said, I will agree with you.

Comment: @pimvdb, Raynos has provided a good example where it *does* break for images in older versions of IE. It's not supposed to work that way, but what can you do. I redact my previous statement.

Answer (score 5):

Just for the records, completeness and for those that didn't know: *Without an event handler*, a good alternative would be to poll for jQuery every X amount of time. Ex:

```
function is_jquery_here(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      if(window.jQuery){
         my_jquery_code_here();
      } else {
        is_jquery_here();
      }
    }, 300);
}
is_jquery_here();
```

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this, but it's a working solution.

Comment: no me but i'd, I'm personally always against any "timeout function" usage anywhere in any occasion]

Answer (score 2):

Not every browser supports `.onload` for script elements, so if you need cross-browser compatibility, use `onreadystatechange` as well:

```
function load( src, callback )
{
  var s,r;
  s = document.createElement('script');
  s.type = 'text/javascript';
  s.src = src;
  s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if ( !r && ( !this.readyState || this.readyState == 'complete' ) )
    {
      r = 1;
      callback();
    }
  };
  document.body.appendChild(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery script in the page and you just want to make sure its loaded first, then I'd highly recommend that one

```
window.onload = function() {
  //.....your jquery code....
};
```

Answer (score -5):

Michael is right. You could also use this shorthand

```
$(function() {
    // Code for on docload here
});
```

Comment: He is not. What if jQuery is not loaded before this is executed? Everything will fail. ;)