# Get absolute filepath

Tags: java, spring-mvc, absolute-path, fileitem

I have org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile object and i need to get absolute file path on client device. Thanks
[image: debugger screenshot]

I need to show picture to user, without saving on server.

Comment: You cannot do that for security reasons. The only way I know to circumvent this is by using flash / silverlight / java applet or something that works on the browser, and as part of uploading the file it also sends the path on the client.

Comment: As i understood file saves in tomcat temp directory.I need to show picture to user, without saving on server.

Comment: Therefore use javascript FileApi and Canvas. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to get the full path of client device, maybe you can spy the user's username or OS what he dont like you to know.

Use FileApi from Javascript instead ([How can I draw an image from the HTML5 File API on Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775767/how-can-i-draw-an-image-from-the-html5-file-api-on-canvas)).

Comment: spring:form sends to the server(and page will reload) -> bean validates -> if validation failed, bean returns to jsp. Do i have to save image on server to show image to user?

Comment: No, you dont have to save the image on server to show the image to the user! See the Article, folow the fiddle-link. But you need JavaScript experience.

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers will not include the path information on the client.

For example if you have a `CommonsMultipartFile` you can call `getFileItem()` to receive a `FileItem` and then from the `FileItem` call `getName()`.

For example:

```
commonsMultipartFile.getFileItem().getName();
```

However as the documentation states:

> Returns the original filename in the client's filesystem, as provided
>   by the browser (or other client software). In most cases, this will be
>   the base file name, without path information. However, some clients,
>   such as the Opera browser, do include path information.