# How to convert HTML to HTML5 canvas and download it as PNG file

Tags: javascript, html, css

Whenever I type something in input box it'll will reflect and can drag and drop that text. Now it is HTML format.

I have to convert the HTML content to image file and download it.

Here is the

```
<a href="http://codepen.io/vengreat/pen/pgROpr">CodePen</a>
```

Please check it out.

Comment: Refer this: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a button that will create image of the "then-generated" image, and use the following code to capture the text as image using HTML5 Canvas.

```
function Capture() { 
        html2canvas(document.body, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      },
       width: 500,
       height: 500
    });
};
```

Since it's not possible to invoke `SaveAs` directly from HTML, you can Right-click and click ***Save As*** button to download the image.

P.S. Don't forget to add the `html2canvas` reference in your webpage.

Working [CodePen](http://codepen.io/snazzysanoj/pen/ZQezZg).

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: can you give sample button and how to set height and width please.

Comment: Hi snazzy sanoj thank you. but background image is not shown in canvas fromat why ?

Comment: You can read about that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775767/how-can-i-draw-an-image-from-the-html5-file-api-on-canvas) Please upvote and mark my answer as accepted if it worked for you. :)

Comment: Did you try saving it as `.png` file?

Comment: There are ways to force-download the image. Refer this: http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/7PRNN/

Comment: @RayonDabre Thank you so much. I never knew I was able to invoke the `Save As` dialog. :)